# How to implement core spotlight indexing in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios14, corespotlight

I am having issue with making Core Data searchable using Core Spotlight in iOS. I checked `Index For Spotlight` for some attributes like name, date modified for a. I subclassed `NSCoreDataCoreSpotlightDelegate` and called `setOption(spotlightDelegate, forKey: NSCoreDataCoreSpotlightExporter)` on persistent container's store description before loading persistent stores. In the logs, CoreData prints that it has successfully initialised by `NSCoreDataCoreSpotlightDelegate` subclass, but I am not able to see any record in spotlight.

Do I have to set Spotlight Display Name for entity also?

Comment: can you show please your code , where you implement it?

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is old but I would recommend you check out https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10098. This session is all about the updates to the NSCoreDataCoreSpotlightDelegate in iOS 15.

- Discover how Core Data can surface data from your app in Spotlight with as little as two lines of code.
- Learn how to make that data discoverable in Spotlight search and to customize how it is presented to people on device.
- See how to implement full-text search within your app, driven completely with the data indexed by Spotlight.

There is an associated sample application to demonstrate how these new capabilities work.

Comment: Hi @davidstites, thanks sharing for the link to the WWDC Session, I too saw it this WWDC and it is quite helpful. 